# Touchable Without Feedback Shrinking my View

Tags: react-native

I am doing a swipe to delete option in my ListItem.

It was looking good, until I added the touchable without feedback component.

Once I did that, the view container shrunk. However the white area below it is still touchable.

I have tried to make the container flex: 1 but it did not work.

Any ideas?

```
 function ListItemDeleteAction({ onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="trash-can"
          color={colors.white}
          size={35}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.danger,
    width: 70,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I figured it out for anyone else looking for an answer, I just enclosed the touchablewithoutfeedback in the view.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="trash-can"
          color={colors.white}
          size={35}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
```